# Use same id for any element in two different views of a controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am just curious that can we use same `id` of any element say `div` in two different views of the same controller (in any framework).

**Note** _ It's working ,when i'm assigning dynamic value to div . can any one explain , why it's working because as far i know it'd not work . I'm using `Ruby on Rails` 

***Review***: I'm not asking for using duplicate id on the one view of a controller , I'm asking for having two different pages but same controller and the same `js` file

Answer (score 1):

It's not impossible, even it doesn't raise errors or anything it is still wrong to use same ID for different elements. ID should be unique but you have to make sure that stays that way. RoR has nothing to do it.

If you need an identifier to use in some JS code, I would suggest create an id like `"my-model-#{id}"`(although not CSS friendly) where only the id is dynamically changed. Or use some data attribute on the element like `data-my-unique-id="#{id}"`

For me, I would stay with a data attribute, ID it's reachable on the CSS and that's why it should have a descriptive name and stay like that, avoiding dynamically values.

Answer (score 1):

It works because each view is essentially a different html document. ID of an html element should be unique in a document. But If you need to use same ID for multiple elements across different views, better approach would be to use classes.